How do I choose multiple selectors for a single style in CSS
So, I am a beginenr and I wrote a set of styles like:
.heading-background .author-class .publish-time{
  border: 2px solid black;
}

In index.html I have 3 different heading elements with these different classes; heading-background, author-class and publish-time. I want a border on all of them so I was wondering how to select em all and write only a single line for all of em using different classes.
I tried the aboove code and it didnt work, no error but no result also

Your style-rule doesn't work because of your space " " chars. e.g. in .classA .classB { ... }  it means that the rule only selects .classB elements that are descendants of .classA elements; but to have the rule only apply to elements that have all 3 classes applied (i.e. <h1 class="heading-background author-class publish-time">) you should use .heading-background.author-class.publish-time. Whereas if you want elements with any of those 3 classes to share the same property-values then use commas, e.g. .heading-background, .author-class, .publish-time {

To group CSS selectors in a style sheet, use commas (,) to separate multiple grouped selectors in the style. You can place any valid selector in a group, and all elements in the document that match all the grouped elements will have the same style based on that style property.
.heading-background, .author-class, .publish-time {
  border: 2px solid black;
}

